# Control table views inside a single collection view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Hey everyone I have sort of a problem here and I’ll try to explain best as I can. So I have a collection view with a collection view cell and embedded inside that cell is a table view, and with that table view I want to return 3 (for testing more in the future) cells, which would return 3 tableviews. With those tableviews I want to have different types of data, but I want to know how I can do that or if its possible with just one table view in my storyboard. I have already attempted to try this but everything returns as nil. Thanks in advance!

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    if tableView == tableview1 {

        return 0;

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {

        return 3
    }

    return 0;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if tableView == tableview1 {
        return 2;

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if tableView == tableview1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if tableView == tableview1 {

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Homeroom"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "8:15 AM - 9:00 AM"
        cell.selectionStyle = .None

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test Table 2 "
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "1:30 PM - 2:30 PM"
        cell.selectionStyle = .None

    }

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add tableviews to cell using xibs or storyboard. and Put all these delegates and data source of tableview inside collectionviewcell class, and tell tableviews also that its datasource and delegates are there in this class. let me know if that works.